# MySQL: Getting only one row for multiple rows with the same date?

Tags: mysql, date

I have a MySQL query and it returns several rows with a date in one column, thats my query:

```
select * from (big subselect) sub
```

I get 6 rows for example and one column in those 6 rows has a date, the column is called my_date. Is there a way to get only those rows that have a date that is not the same day? Example:

```
29.10.2012 01:51:10
29.10.2012 01:51:10
29.10.2012 01:51:10
29.10.2012 02:43:18
29.10.2012 02:43:18
29.10.2012 02:43:18
```

--> I want only one of the rows, because all 6 are the same day.

```
29.10.2012 01:51:10
30.10.2012 01:51:10 --> different
29.10.2012 01:51:10
29.10.2012 02:43:18
29.10.2012 02:43:18
29.10.2012 02:43:18
```

--> I want 2 rows, because there are 2 different days

The my_date column is not the only one in each row, but I want it as criteria. How could I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to supply the rest of the criteria - it depends on what you are doing how the answer would be provided.

Comment: and what's the result you desire?

Comment: Can you please post the query you have and the tables' structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to select only these `MAX(my_date)`, but you will need to group by some other filed. Something like this:

```
select s1.*
from sub as s1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT MAX(my_date) AS MaxDate, SomeId
   FROM sub
   GROUP BY someId
) AS s2 ON s1.my_date = MaxDate AND s1.SomeId = s2.SomeId;
```

Comment: Wouldnt max(my_date) only return the latest date? In my case the 30.10.2012 01:51:10?

Comment: @user1856596 - You have to use a group by to return max of date for each group. Can you please post the tables' structures?

Comment: @user1856596 Just the columns involved in your query. It will be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can group only dates like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sub
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(my_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/587ef/1)

Result:

```
| ID |                        MY_DATE |
---------------------------------------
|  1 | October, 29 2012 01:51:10+0000 |
|  2 | October, 30 2012 01:51:10+0000 |
```